# Selenium problem locating by DOM

Tags: selenium

I'm trying to use the DOM to locate a form element in Selenium but I can't get it to work. Even if I use the example in the Selenium documentation it still fails, for example with this html...

```
 <html>
  <body>
   <form id="loginForm">
    <input name="username" type="text" />
    <input name="password" type="password" />
    <input name="continue" type="submit" value="Login" />
    <input name="continue" type="button" value="Clear" />
   </form>
 </body>
 <html>
```

and this command in the Selenium IDE...

```
verifyElementPresent
```

with target...

```
 dom=document.forms['loginForm']
```

I get [error] false in the log.
The 'getElementById' example in the documentation does work, but none of the others.

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong here?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why it's not working (I can replicate the problem), but perhaps there's a better way to locate your target element? I would recommend locating by ID/name, falling back to CSS or XPath.

Answer (score 0):

The format to locate a element is-

i) document.forms[index of the form].elements[index of the element]

**index of the form** = the index number (starting at 0) of the form with respect to the whole page, **index of the element** = the index number (starting at 0) of the element with respect to the whole form that contains it.

ii) document.forms[“name of the form”].elements[“name of the element”]

**name of the form** = the value of the name attribute of the form tag that contains the element you want to access, **name of the element** = the value of the name attribute of the element you wish to access

iii) document.getElementById(“id of the element”)

**id of the element** = this is the value of the ID attribute of the element to be accessed. This value should always be enclosed in a pair of parentheses (“”).

iv)document.getElementsByName(“name”)[index]

**name** = name of the element as defined by its ‘name’ attribute, **index** = an integer that indicates which element within getElementsByName’s array will be used.